# RoR: Sorting paginated products on an endless page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I am using will_paginate gem to paginate products on an endless/infinite scroll page. The pagination works fine.

But whyen I try to sort the products listed on that page, only the products that have been loaded upto that point get sorted, and the remaining products appear in random order after loading.

Following is my controller, sorting is done based on `order` parameter :

```
def index
    @order = params[:order]                                                 
    @query = params[:tag]                                                   
    @taxon = params[:taxon]                                                 
    if @order.nil?
        @order = "relevance"                                                        
    end
    @products = queryTags(params, @taxon)                                       
    if ! @products.nil?
        if @order == "pricelow"
            @products = @products.sort_by{ |k| k['variants'][0]['Price'] }
        elsif @order == "pricehigh"
            @products = @products.sort_by{ |k| -k['variants'][0]['Price'] }
        elsif @order == "relevance"
            @products = @products.sort_by{ |k| -k['productRelevance'] }
        elsif @order == "pop"
            @product_group = @products.map{|product| product['id']}
            @result = Product.where(id: @product_group).descend_by_popularity
            @products = @result.map{|r| @products.find{|p| p['id'] == r['id']}}
        end
    end
    @productsProxy = Array.new
    if @products != nil
        @products.each do |p|
            tempProduct = ProductProxy.new(p)
            @productsProxy.push(tempProduct)
        end
    else
        @productProxy = []
    end
    if @order == "new"
        @productsProxy.sort!{ |a,b| b.productAvailableDateTs <=> a.productAvailableDateTs }
    end
    @productsProxy = @productsProxy.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    respond_with("Search Results") do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
        format.xml { render :xml => @productsProxy, :only => [:name, :permalink, :description, :mrp], :methods => [:designer, :taxons, :price] }
    end
end
```

Why does the sorting happen only for the loaded products even when I am sorting the entire `@productsProxy` array.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, the request to next page contains params {order: 'new'}. for regular pageination links use

```
will_paginate(@productProxy, :params => { :order => params[:order] || 'new' })
```